# is it possible to use a MetadataType attribute with an interface: [MetadataType(GetType(iPerson))]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is it possible to use a `MetadataType` attribute with an interface? This does not work `[MetadataType(GetType(iPerson))]`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow :) . Try typeof(iPerson) instead of GetType()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, its not possible, you will have to put there some concrete type, in order for it to work.

From docs:

> When you apply this attribute, you must adhere to the following usage constraints:
>
> - The attribute can only be applied to a class.
> - The attribute cannot be inherited by derived classes.
> - The attribute can be applied only one time.

Here is more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute?view=netcore-3.1